# How to Interpret model learning curve (epoch wise accuracy & loss curve for training & validation data)?

Tags: validation, keras, deep-learning, training-data

here I am working with 1D cnn based model,i am not understanding the model learning curve, as the test/validation accuracy curve are fluctuating, and overall model performance is about 70%, On the contrary the validation loss just saturated and fluctuated? how should i interpret my result and what changes should I consider?

I have used adam optimizer.

[image: Model Learning Curve , which represent epoch wise model accuracy and loss]

Answer (score 0):

You should try using augmentation of training images or use more training image. The fluctuations in the validation data accuracy means whatever it is learning during training it is not able to apply in validation or real life properly and it is not desired from a model.